# Video Streaming for a IIS hosted MVC web application using HTML5 video

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, html5-video, http-streaming

I was following article on http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/easy-handling-of-http-range-requests-in-asp-net and wrote simple MVC application to stream large video files.

Here is my code with slight modifications to the code in that tutorial,

```
internal static void StreamVideo(string fullpath, HttpContextBase context)
    {
        long size, start, end, length, fp = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
        {

            size = reader.BaseStream.Length;
            start = 0;
            end = size - 1;
            length = size;
            // Now that we've gotten so far without errors we send the accept range header
            /* At the moment we only support single ranges.
             * Multiple ranges requires some more work to ensure it works correctly
             * and comply with the spesifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2
             *
             * Multirange support annouces itself with:
             * header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
             *
             * Multirange content must be sent with multipart/byteranges mediatype,
             * (mediatype = mimetype)
             * as well as a boundry header to indicate the various chunks of data.
             */
            context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + size);
            // header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            // multipart/byteranges
            // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"]))
            {
                long anotherStart = start;
                long anotherEnd = end;
                string[] arr_split = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"].Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("=") });
                string range = arr_split[1];

                // Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range
                if (range.IndexOf(",") > -1)
                {
                    // (?) Shoud this be issued here, or should the first
                    // range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
                    // we output the whole content?
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");

                }

                // If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
                // If not, we forward the file pointer
                // And make sure to get the end byte if spesified
                if (range.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    // The n-number of the last bytes is requested
                    anotherStart = size - Convert.ToInt64(range.Substring(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    arr_split = range.Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("-") });
                    anotherStart = Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[0]);
                    long temp = 0;
                    anotherEnd = (arr_split.Length > 1 && Int64.TryParse(arr_split[1].ToString(), out temp)) ? Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[1]) : size;
                }
                /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
                 * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
                 */
                // End bytes can not be larger than $end.
                anotherEnd = (anotherEnd > end) ? end : anotherEnd;
                // Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct.
                if (anotherStart > anotherEnd || anotherStart > size - 1 || anotherEnd >= size)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullpath);
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
                }
                start = anotherStart;
                end = anotherEnd;

                length = end - start + 1; // Calculate new content length
                fp = reader.BaseStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
            }
        }
        // Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
        // Start buffered download
        context.Response.WriteFile(fullpath, fp, length);
        context.Response.End();

    }
```

When I streaming large capacity(around 700MB) video in a network using above code the starting of video is very slow (around 1-2 minutes). In this stage I checked the network requests and it seems browser ask for video and waiting for a response from server. This is really annoying for the user.

Then once it started video is playing smoothly (It is a 720P resolution video and as my network connection is good video is playing very smoothly).

But when I do a seek with controls on html video player, then same issue happens and I have to wait another 1-2 minutes till response completed.

I am using IIS7 (MVC4). If I play the same video which located inside of IIS dir then I can play it without mentioned delay. Also if the video is located outside of IIS folder but if it within the same machine that hosted IIS then also no issues.

I am having this issue when I have video in a network location which is a different machine that IIS hosted.

So conclusion is, 
This is not because of user browser trying to load large video in to browser. It is something between video share machine vs IIS.

Any idea about resolving this?

Regards,
-Lasith